# How to execute multiple DB queries?

Tags: magento2, database, database-connection

My query is:

```
/**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
  */
private $connection;

$query =
            <<<SQL
                LOCK TABLE {$tablename} WRITE;
                SET  @num := 0;
                UPDATE {$tablename} SET {$idField} = @num := (@num+1);
                ALTER TABLE {$tablename} AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
                UNLOCK TABLES;
SQL;
$this->connection->query($query);
```

I've got an error in CLI:

[image: Multi queries forbidden]

**How to run the query simultaneously?**

Comment: Why not running them into 5 different and sequential query ? Which is what sql is probably doing anyway.

Comment: It's one of possible solutions. But: Suppose 3d query is failed. Is table leave locked?

Comment: Sort of direction of solution. We can fetch PDO object: 

        `/** @var \PDO $pdo */`
        `$pdo = $this->connection->getConnection();`
        `$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 0);`
        `$this->connection->exec($query);`

Comment: Well I would say you can try catch each request and in the failing part you can always run the unlock just to be sure i would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private ?AdapterInterface $connection = null;

private method doMultipleQueriesAndDoUnlockNoMatterWhat(): void
{
    $query1 = sprintf('LOCK TABLE %s WRITE', $tablename);
    $query2 = '';
    $query3 = '';
    $query4 = '';
    $query5 = 'UNLOCK TABLES';

    try {
        $this->connection->exec($query1);
        $this->connection->exec($query2);
        $this->connection->exec($query3);
        $this->connection->exec($query4);
    } catch(\Throwable $e) {
    
    } finally {
        $this->connection->exec($query5);
    }
}
```

You can use `finally` to proceed with some logic no matter what happens in the try-catch-block.

Comment: It looks like the most possible solution. I suggest use query() instead of exec(). Good idea with `finally`

Comment: Best solution here would be to not use `exec` or `query` at all, instead have the right abstraction layer available to do it; but it would require you to write more code.